# How to sync a Git repository with a fork which is now hosted in my organization's local Git Server

Tags: javascript, git, github

We forked a repository from github, and made some project related modifications to that but hosted it in our private Git Server. The actual repository now has some important performance improvements. How can I sync our forked ( & modified) repository with the original repository.

Is manual (file by file) comparison and merging, my only option ?

(We have hosted the repository in Bonobo Git Server)

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request

Comment: Just pull the changes from the original repository. Only if you want them to take your changes into their repository you need to create a pull request.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I read it as "update the original repo with our changes", on second read this doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

add remote upstream of the repo on GitHub in your repo:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/whoever/whatever.git
```

fetch upstream:

```
git fetch upstream
```

checkout to your main branch - e.g. `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

then [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) `upstream` to `master`:

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

Nevertheless, if there are a lot of differences between the original repo and forked repo, then rebase may not be smooth and something may break in the project, so keep that fact in mind. In git you can always revert or discard your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "sync" your private Git server with a public Github repo, directly.

Instead, you should fork the public Github repo to your own account on Github, so that you have a Github-hosted clone to which you have write access.

Then, you should add that Github-hosted clone as a remote to your local clone of your private fork, and push your changes to that clone.

Now you can open a pull request from your Github-hosted clone to the original Github repo.